# How to multi thread with signal event from other thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list write command that need to infinite loop as thread by turn. Each call thread need to wait recv method to match OK or ERROR conditional. Then, call next command again with thread. The command in below. Current, the output buffer in unorder. It can't use join. Because, write command to fast than income buffer. The only ways is to pause after call write method and wait recv method a signal conditional match OK or ERROR. Then, iterate next command again and so on. How to achieve this?

> AT+CGMI
>
> AT+CGSN

```
class Device():
   __command = 'none'

   def __init__(self, port, baudrate):
       self.__port = port
       self.__baudrate = baudrate

   def open(self):
       try:
           self.handle = serial.Serial(self.__port, self.__baudrate)

           return True
       except SerialException as e:
           error = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(e))
           self.__error = {'port': error[0], 'description': error[1]}

           return None

  def __state(self):
      if self.open() is None:
           if self.__error['description'] == 'Access is denied.':
               return True
           elif self.__error['description'] == 'Port is already open.':
               return True
           else:
               return False
      else:
          return True

  def recv(self):
      while True:
          if self.__state():
              buffer = self.handle.readline()

              if buffer == b'AT+CGSN\r\r\n':
                  data = []

                  while True:
                      buffers = self.handle.readline()

                      data.append(buffers.decode('UTF-8').strip())

                      if buffers == b'OK\r\n':
                          print(data[0])
                          self.__command = 'done'
                          break
                      elif buffers == b'ERROR\r\n':
                          break

              elif buffer == b'AT+CGMI\r\r\n':
                  data = []

                  while True:
                      buffers = self.handle.readline()

                      data.append(buffers.decode('UTF-8').strip())

                      if buffers == b'OK\r\n':
                          print(data[0])
                          self.__command = 'done'
                          break
                      elif buffers == b'ERROR\r\n':
                          break

          else:
              print(self.__error['port'] + ' ' + self.__error['description'])

              time.sleep(1)

 def write(self, command):
     if self.__state():
         self.__command = 'waiting'

         self.handle.write(command.encode('UTF-8') + b'\r')

         while self.__command == 'waiting':
               if self.__command == 'done':
                   break

device = Device('COM12', 9600)

device.open()

recv = threading.Thread(target=device.recv)
recv.start()

commands = ['AT+CGSN', 'AT+CGMI']

while True:
    for command in commands:
        device.write(command)
```

Comment: Signals are a very specific context in programming. Do you mean signals or just "events"? Your code does not seem to use signals.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta what the differents signal and event? I need to wait response from recv method after call imei thread or manufacturer thread in turn and infinite loop. recv method in default will run forever from start program. Only write method that run in turn as thread with command. What the appropriate to call it signal or event?

Comment: @davidstephen  ***"call it signal or event?"***: [module-signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal) involve **os**, [Event Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) is python `threading` module only.

Comment: @davidstephen Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC) In particular when speaking of signals we generally refer to POSIX signals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals which include stuff like `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Even i already read that 2 days ago to use lock. I still can't figure it out. But i try to use global attribute with private attribute __command. then loop in bottom. But it only loop index 1 from list. what the problem? I edited my current code.